# How to merge shards in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I launched a ElasticSearch instance several months ago but I overestimated a sizing of an average shard. My shards are fairly small now 400mb max. and I found out that a recommended size should be approx. 50gb (based on a stackoverflow search). I also ran out of maximum shard count and I had to reconfigure it. But the proper approach is to change a logic of shards and basically make shards larger. It is completely doable in my case but the question is how to deal with already existing shards. I can certainly replay data but it will take a LOT of time. So is there a better way how to merge smaller shards into big ones?

Comment: Hello, you do have a few choices. [Shrink API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-shrink-index.html) is one of them as @moliware mentioned. You can also try to merge indices and limit number of shards with [_reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153683/elasticsearch-how-to-merge-indexes-into-one-index/47054501#47054501) for examples of how to limit the number of indices

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't merge shards on the fly. This used to be one of those situations where you have to reindex your data.

Elasticsearch now provides a way of making this situation a bit less painful. [Shrink API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-shrink-index.html) allows you to create a new index whose number of primary shards is a factor of the number of the primary shards of the source index. For example if your index has 12 shards, the shrunk index can have 6, 4, 2, 1 primary shards.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanx. This helps me.