# ElasticSearch - How to merge indexes into one index?

Tags: elasticsearch

My cluster has an index for each day since a few months ago,
5 shards each index (the default),
and I can't run queries on the whole cluster because there are too many shards (over 1000).

The document IDs are automatically generated.

How can I combine the indexes into one index, deal with conflicting ids (if conflicts are even possible), and change the types?

I am using ES version 5.2.1

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: I am using ES version 5.2.1

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Common problem that is visible only after few months of using ELK stack with `filebeat` creating indices day by day. There is a few options to fix the performance issue here.

## [`_forcemerge`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-forcemerge.html)

First you can use [`_forcemerge`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-forcemerge.html) to limit the numer of segments inside  Lucene index. Operation won't limit or merge indices but will improve the performance of Elasticsearch.

```bash
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/logstash-2017.07*/_forcemerge?max_num_segments=1'
```

This will run through the whole month indices and force merge segments. When done for every month, it should improve the Elasticsearch performance a lot. In my case CPU usage went down from 100% to 2.7%.

Unfortunately this won't solve the shards problem.

## [`_reindex`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-reindex.html)

> Please read the [`_reindex`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-reindex.html) documentation and backup your database before continue.

As [tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153683/elasticsearch-how-to-merge-indexes-into-one-index?answertab=votes#tab-top) mentioned. If you want to limit number of shards or indices there is no other option than use [`_reindex`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-reindex.html) to merge few indices into one. This can take a while depending on the number and size of indices you have.

#### Destination index

You can create the destination index beforehand and specify number of shards it should contain. This will ensure your final index will have the number of shards you need.

```bash
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/new-logstash-2017.07.01?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1 
        }
    }
}
'
```

#### Limiting number of shards

If you want to limit number of shards per index you can run [`_reindex`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-reindex.html) one to one. In this case there should be no entries dropped as it will be exact copy but with smaller number of shards.

```bash
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "conflicts": "proceed",
    "source": {
        "index": "logstash-2017.07.01"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "logstash-v2-2017.07.01",
        "op_type": "create"
    }
}
'
```

After this operation you can remove old index and use new one. Unfortunately if you want to use old name you need to [`_reindex`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-reindex.html) one more time with new name. If you decide to do that

> DON'T FORGET TO SPECIFY NUMBER OF SHARDS FOR THE NEW INDEX! By default it will fall back to 5.

#### Merging multiple indices and limiting number of shards

```bash
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "conflicts": "proceed",
    "source": {
        "index": "logstash-2017.07*"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "logstash-2017.07",
        "op_type": "create"
    }
}
'
```

When done you should have all entries from `logstash-2017.07.01` to `logstash-2017.07.31` merged into `logstash-2017.07`. Note that the old indices must be deleted manually.

Some of the entries can be overwritten or merged, depending which `conflicts` and `op_type` option you choose.

## Further steps

#### Create new indices with one shard

You can set up [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-templates.html) that will be used every time new `logstash` index is created.

```bash
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_template/template_logstash?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "template" : "logstash-*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    }
}
'
```

This will ensure every new index created that match `logstash-` in name to have only one shard.

#### Group logs by month

If you don't stream too many logs you can set up your `logstash` to group logs by month.

```js
// file: /etc/logstash/conf.d/30-output.conf

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost"]
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

## Final thoughts

It's not easy to fix initial misconfiguration! Good luck with optimising your Elastic search!

Comment: This is really good information.  The official docs can be difficult to understand when it comes to applying to one's specific instance of ELK.    Like many I came to need to know how to combine indexes after I got a better understanding of what a Shard really is.

Comment: After merging multiple indices you can just give the new index an alias. No need to reindex again to use the old name.

Comment: a comment, "op_type": "create" doesn't create index when u `reindex` you need to create the destination index beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [reindex api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html).

```
POST _reindex
{
 "conflicts": "proceed",
 "source": {
   "index": ["twitter", "blog"],
   "type": ["tweet", "post"]
  },
  "dest": {
  "index": "all_together"
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I think some documents from different indices have the same IDs, so not all the documents end up in the new index :\